# Exporting mysql code from dbdiagram.io and trying to import the schema file in phpmyadmin gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, mysql-error-1064

this is my first post so be kind please ^^

I've first been asked to design a database schema, and I did it by using this tool I've found on the web: https://dbdiagram.io/

Then I have been asked to actually create the database and fill in some fake data to allow other developers to start work.

So I have created a new SQL database to which I've linked phpmyadmin (I knew how to do it from previous basic knowledge of Wordpress) and wanted to import the .SQL file generated by dbdiagram.io

However, when importing the file I get this back:

```
Import has been successfully finished, 22 queries executed. (file_name.sql)

CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY COMMENT 'test',
  `attribute2` enum,
  `attribute3` enum,
  `attribute4` ENUM ('option 1', 'option 2'),
  `attribute5` ENUM ('option 1', 'option 2') COMMENT 'This is a comment'
)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
  `attribute3` enum,
  `attribute4` ENUM ('option1', 'Primary ' at line 3
```

No table or relation has been created.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the point of having an enum field without listing the  values you can choose from?

Comment: Right, I partially misunderstood the meaning of enum. Thank you very much!